# Flask returning 500 Internal error after successful return

Tags: python, python-3.x, http

I have a flask app which sends files for download when certain URL is reached. But as soon as the download is complete, the Browser shows 500 Internal Error even though the file download was successful.

Is it possible to show an empty page instead of Internal error? Since I m returning dynamically created files to download, not sure if I can do it with HTML.

My return statement

```
return send_from_directory(
    os.path.abspath(f'{LOGS_FOLDER}/{SESSION}/'),
    f'logs_{umgebung}_{product}.zip',
    as_attachment=True
)
```

Comment: What's the error in the Flask log? Don't work around it, fix the root cause.

Comment: the Flask Log, shows return 200 and waits for the next request.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have not added a return template or any redirect command. So when python runs the procedure, it stops in this return, without returning a page and thus error 500

Flask simply doesn't know what to return as a page, being confused returns error 500.

You can indeed return a blank page with the proper command.

EDIT:
A good solution to your problem is **Dynamic Routing**

[Creating Multiple Routes and Dynamic Content in Flask](http://www.compjour.org/lessons/flask-single-page/multiple-dynamic-routes-in-flask/)
 this article offers a fair example on how to do this.

The main idea is to have a variable that changes the URL pattern each time you want to return to user something specific. You use a single template for your pages and have multiple URLs leading to multiple pages with the same structure but with different results.

Comment: But how do I make multiple return commands for a path?

Comment: With dynamic routing

Comment: Could you add an example of dynamic routing in here?

Comment: @Vini I edited my answer explaining the idea ang giving a fair example with a link